# Preventing WKWebView from automatically highlighting plain text as clickable URL

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have the following HTML content to be rendered in a `WKWebView`:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div>Here goes plain text google.com type of content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I load it in Safari, it's rendered as expected:
[image]

But if I load it in my iOS app in a `WKWebView` using `webview.loadHTMLString` method, it automatically highlights the url and makes it clickable:

```swift
webview.loadHTMLString("<html><body><div>Here goes plain text google.com type of content</div></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

[image]

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either create your wkwebview from your own empty configuration like below

```
import UIKit
import WebKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView!


override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><div>Here goes plain text google.com type of content</div></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
}


}
```

Or you if you are using storyboard, please disable link detector in xcode attributes inspector

[image]